# asp: open "save-as" dialog for PDF (using asppdf + xmlhttp)

Tags: pdf, asp-classic

i'm using asp + asppdf (a component for creating pdf files). 
asppdf has a method called SaveHTTP which causes the browser to open the "save-as" dialog for saving the pdf. so the component is sending the pdf as binary data to the browser.

my question: i'd like to load the pdf via xmlhttp + then open that dialog.
loading works (i'm getting the data) - but i'm not sure how to call the save-as dialog.

any ideas if it's possible?

thanks

Comment: Are you trying to do this using AJAX?

Comment: i'm using jQuery and $.ajax (sending a 'post')

Answer (score 2):

<strike>You need to add a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header to the HTTP response.</strike>

**EDIT**: It is not possible to show a save dialog using AJAX.
Instead, you can set `location.href` to the PDF URL (with `Content-Disposition: attachment`), which will do what you're trying to accomplish.  (You could also POST a `<form>` in a hidden `<iframe>`)

Comment: thanks for your answer. in my serverscript i added the header like this: 
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""myfile.pdf"""
should be right - i can see the header in firebug but - no save-as-dialog :(

Comment: Try setting  `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: already did - nothing happens still ..
my code:

m_file = "mypdf.pdf"
Response.ContentType = "pdf"
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=""" & m_file & """"
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"